# Cheese Extract - How to Use it?

Tags: cheese

I've recently bought cheese extract (or essence - the seller didn't know the difference and the bottle says 'cheese flavour' and smells like a room full of cheddar).

I've never used it before but was sure there was something online for how to use it - but I can't find a thing. I just find recipes using cheese.

I imagine it's probably used to enhance the cheese flavour of dishes that can't afford to use much cheese but are their recipes that just use it as a flavour enhancer? My sister recently became dairy free (these diet fads are the bane of every family cook)and I thought it would be nice for her to have some flavours she likes.

Please help!

Best regards,

Amber

Comment: Never heard of it, but might be worth trying it in something simple and cheap to make like a cheese sauce. Just to see how it tastes.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. I need to practice with some pie crusts this weekend so I could put some in one of the experiments and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Cheese is often in a recipe for texture as well as flavor: it is stretchy and creamy, as well as "cheesy." One exception would be sauces, or baked into a casserole, in which the cheese is all melted in and is almost entirely there for flavor. I'd suggest attempting a cheddar cheese roux sauce, using soy milk instead of dairy milk and adding a small amount of the cheese extract.

You will need to experiment to get the proportions right, so hopefully your sister likes mac-n-cheese :)